# Is it posible reference to method of the class during class declaration on class level?

Tags: python

I am writing python script for blender. Because of blender specific I have problem with do not exist otherwise.

```
class TREE_OT_assign(bpy.types.Operator):

    names = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=get_items(), update=update())

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        ...
```

In blender, 'names' has to be declared in this place (as class level variable). It can not be declared as None and changed later on. In my script get_items and update are global functions. I want them to be methods of TREE_OT_assign class. Is it possible?

Comment: Why do you want these two functions to be inside your class?

Comment: ...and why can't they be?  I think you have to show us those functions.

Comment: They can be, but if you need to call them statically it's not that easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need/want these two functions to be inside your class. But here are two ways of doing it, one that is safer and another that is easier to read, but can be dangerous in some cases.

#### The safe way

```py
class A: 

  @staticmethod
  def f():
    return 2

  s = f.__func__()

print("Class s = ", id(A.s))
print("Instance s = ", id(A().s))
```

Both print output the same `id` as `s` is a static field from class `A`. You need to call `__func__` on `f` because `f` is not a function, it's a *static method*, adding this `print(type(f))` in the class body would print `<class 'staticmethod'>`. If you have a look at what instance/static/class methods objects look like, you'll see that (amongst other things) they contain a function object that you can access via `__func__`.

This is described in the [data model](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html), either search for "Instance methods", "Static method" or "Class method". In particular:

> Static method objects provide a way of defeating the transformation of function objects to method objects described above.

Where the "method objects" are defined as such:

> An instance method object combines a class, a class instance and any callable object (normally a user-defined function).
>
> Special read-only attributes: `__self__` is the class instance object, `__func__` is the function object …

#### The short way

On the other hand you could just do the following:

```
class A: 

  def f(x):
    return x

  s = f(2)
```

Which may even be "better" in your case, but note that if you do that, then you "won't" be able to call `f` on instances of `A` because `f` will be a `function` (not an instance method object). In other words, what you would be able to do is:

```py
print(A.f(2))
print(A().__class__.f(2))
```

But calling `A().f` directly would not work as expected (and might even be dangerous):

```py
>>> print(A().f(2))  # Not too bad
TypeError: f() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
>>> print(A().f())  # Quite bad
<__main__.A object at 0x7fab441131d0>
```

The last call is equivalent to calling `f` with parameter `x` set to an instance of `A`, ie. `print(A.f(A()))` is equivalent to that last call.

In general I would recommend the first solution, but in your case, the simple version could suffice, just make sure to name your "method" (function) `__<name>` to warn people from outside that they shouldn't use it unless they know what they are doing.

#### What is the best way?

In the end, you would need a pretty good reason to go for any of these two solutions as the one you already have is probably the best (having a function outside your class).

Comment: yes, you were right - I still wonder if there's a way to avoid this complexity

Comment: I edited and tried to address that too, but the solution is not perfect either :p

Comment: It SHOULD work my way, lol :o) - Glad you were here.  Would hate leaving a wrong answer.  I gave your answer my thumbs up

Comment: I'm pretty sure someone will come and find how my answer is also wrong

Comment: I just want to have clean code. I am not using this functions anywhere else, so first solution works for me just fine. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Silly my. Solution was so easy.

Instead of:

```
class TREE_OT_assign(bpy.types.Operator):

    names = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=get_items(), update=update())

    def invoke(self, context, event):
```

Just use:

```
class TREE_OT_assign(bpy.types.Operator):

    def get_items(........

    def update(.........

    names = bpy.props.EnumProperty(items=get_items, update=update)

    def invoke(self, context, event):
```

I tried this before, but I put methods definition below "names" variable definition :/